# I want to add word "movie" before posts name in all url in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/{{movie}}/watch-appetite-for-love-2016-free-on-123movieshub/

I want all my url to show movie word before postname

Answer (score 0):

By setting this custom permalink value **`/movie/%postname%/`** as **Custom Structure** at `/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you would benefit from using a custom post type. These take on the URL of their name by default if you have pretty urls. You can also force the slug you want. This is a basic post type there are a lot more options on the [Wordpress Developer Codex.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

```
function create_movie_post_type() {
  register_post_type( 'movies',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Movies' ),
        'singular_name' => __( 'Movie' )
      ),
      'public' => true,
      'has_archive' => true,
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'movie'),
    )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'create_movie_post_type' );
```

This gives you a lot more control over that particular post type and keeps it separate from the native "post".

Comment: Thanks Kyon147, it works but need to replace register_post_type first param to posts rather than, can you please tell me if its all right if I have only movie type post in my website..?

Comment: Sorry, can you explain what you mean? Do you mean you only want movies and not the default "posts"?

Comment: Thanks Kyon147 for helping me out. I checked over all pages and your solution works a charm.

Comment: Great to hear, if you have any issues with 404 or pages not found. You sometimes need to refresh the URL rewrites by just going to the permalinks settings page. It sounds like you have already done so though :)